# Arduino IDE menu doesn't display properly (missing letters)

Tags: ide

I have just installed newest version of Arduino 1.7.10 from arduino.org. 
It has this problem that its menu are not displaying properly - when I hover mouse over items in menu they either disappear completely or some of the letters are missing. Sometimes the whole menu (like 'tools' menu) won't even display. Dialog windows (like "Do you want to save your changes") also suffer from this problem.

I have Windows 7 and I just installed newest version of Java to see if this helps, but it doesn't. 
Have any of you had such problem?

Comment: Could you please add a picture to your question?

Comment: Do you have the same problem with version 1.6.8?

Comment: Installing 1.6.8 helped. Now it works. I don't why.

Answer (score 1):

I've never had this problem, but here are some things you might want to look at.

- Did you install it from an administrator account and use "run as administrator"?  If not, uninstall and reinstall.
- Its possible that you are missing a font, god knows which one.  Go and look at the Arduino source on GitHub(?) and find any TTF files and install them.
- Does this version support Windows 7?
- What version did you have previously? Did you uninstall it before installing this?
- If you didn't have a version before this one, uninstall this version go and get 1.5 or 1.6 and install that, then install 1.7 over the top.

Good luck, and keep monitoring the Arduino.org forums because if it is a problem with the app then they will start screaming quite quickly.